# How do I remove the tibble from an image?

Tags: r, image, r-markdown, tibble

I am trying to upload an image in to a R Markdown template but every time I try to do so the tibble is added above the image and I don't know how to remove the tibble while keeping the image how it is.

### Below is the code I have used

```
facebook <- image_read('//ecfle35/STAFF-HOME$/MaxEmery/My Pictures/Successful post images/facebook oct.png')
print(facebook)
```

### The end result

[image: Click here to view]

I'd like to keep the image the same just remove the tibble does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `image_read` try using the following, which is made for including figures in R Markdown:

```
knitr::include_graphics('PATH_TO_FILE')
```